# How to tune or rewrite this query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using JPA 2.1 and a SQL Server database. Here are the tables (the syntax is for PostgreSQL because it was easiest to write for me at the moment):

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id serial primary key,
    locked boolean,
    name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE subscriptions 
(
    id serial,
    name varchar(20),
    id_user integer references users 
);
```

I want to select all active (not locked) users that do not have a subscription with a specific name. A user may have no subscription or may also have multiple subscriptions.

The SQL version of my JPQL query that I have at the moment is

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE locked = false 
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT id_user 
                 FROM subscriptions 
                 WHERE name = 'premium')
```

I have read somewhere that a SQL Server will execute the nested SELECT for every result row of the outer SELECT. Is this true even if the result set of the nested SELECT will not change as the query is executed like in this case?

This query has horrible runtime performance as the tables grow. How can this query be rewritten or tuned in SQL Server? Maybe using a JOIN?

Comment: The SQL Server optimizer is cost based so it should (in theory) generate the most optimal plan for semantically identical queries. Add primary key, unique constraints, and indexes to your question. Lack of proper indexes may contribute to performance issues. The symptom that performance degrades with table size suggests full scans.

Comment: "I have read somewhere that a SQL Server will execute the nested SELECT for every result row of the outer SELECT" - not true. It will use set-based operations wherever it can.

Comment: @SurprisedCoconut Can you please post sample data? While the comments above are correct, you can perhaps re-write it with a simple join.

Comment: Although you tagged this question with `sql-server`, the data types suggest a different DBMS (PostgreSQL?). Please edit tags accordingly. Regardless, an index on the `subscriptions` table `name` column will likely improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> have read somewhere that a SQL Server will execute the nested SELECT for every result row of the outer SELECT

Not true at all.

And this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE locked = false 
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT id_user 
                 FROM subscriptions 
                 WHERE name != 'premium')
```

Would give you all users who are not locked, and who have no non-premium subscriptions.

To get all the non-locked users who do not have a premium subscription would be like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u
WHERE locked = 0 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM subscriptions 
                where id_user = u.id
                 and name = 'premium')
```

And to test stuff like this in SQL Server, get SQL Server Management Studio (or similar), and run a script like this:

```
use tempdb
go
--drop table subscriptions 
--drop table users
go

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int primary key,
  locked bit,
  name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE subscriptions (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(20),
  id_user int references users 
);

go

with N as 
(
 select row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
 from sys.objects o, sys.columns c, sys.columns c2
)
insert into users (id,locked,name)
select top 10000 i, case when i%100 = 0 then 1 else 0 end, concat('user',i) 
from N;


with N as 
(
 select row_number() over (order by (select null)) i
 from sys.objects o, sys.columns c, sys.columns c2
)
insert into subscriptions(id,name,id_user)
select top 100000 i, case when i%100 = 0  then 'premium' else 'standard' end, i%10000 + 1
from N;


go

SELECT * 
FROM users u
WHERE locked = 0 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM subscriptions 
                 where id_user = u.id
                 and name = 'premium')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may gain a *little* in performance by transforming your query into `not exists()`:

```
select * 
from dbo.users u
where locked = 0
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from dbo.subscriptions s
    where s.id_user = u.id
      and s.name = 'premium'
  )
```

- [Should I use `not in()`, `outer apply()`, `left outer join`, `except`, or `not exists()`? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

---

You can also improve performance by having the proper supporting index on `subscriptions`, for example:

```
create nonclustered index ix_subscriptions_id_user_name 
  on dbo.subscriptions (id_user)
    include (name);
```

You could go a step further and make it a filtered index, but that may not be a significant boost in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have indexes created on joined columns, try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users AS A
LEFT JOIN subscriptions as B
ON B.id_user = A.id
WHERE A.locked = 'false' AND B.name != 'premium' AND B.id_user IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `LEFT JOIN`, of course if create index on join condition, query become so faster.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN subscriptions s
ON s.id_user = u.id
WHERE u.locked = 'false' 
AND s.name != 'premium' 
AND s.id_user IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a clustered index on subscriptions. Maintaining indexes on a heap can be a nightmare if the table is very large. I would probably suggest clustering on id_User.

```
CREATE TABLE subscriptions 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    id_user INT
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CL_id_User ON Subscriptions (id_User)

CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    locked BIT,
    name varchar(20),
    CONSTRAINT PK_users PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
);
```

Then Create a nonclustered index on Subscriptions and Users. Includes used if you are wanting to pull back all columns from both tables.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Users_Locked ON Users (Locked) INCLUDE (Name);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Subscriptions_Name ON Subscriptions (name);
```

And then have your query look something like the below -

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users u
 WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT s.id_user 
                      FROM Subscriptions s 
                     WHERE s.name = 'Premium') 
   AND u.locked = 0;
```

To go a step further, rather use an ID to determine the subscription type. Indexing integers is far superior to indexing strings in SQL Server.